# How to call a Javascript function from Python requests.get

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I am trying to call a javascript function using Python requests lib, so I can be redirected to another URL containing a PDF file I will then download.

**Steps are:**

1. requests.get(url) from a session;
2. call javascript function embeded in the current web page;
3. download the binary content to a PDF file;

Is it possible to do it **using only requests** lib?

## What I have so far - which throws an Exception:

```
import requests
import shutil
import os

main_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(url, verify=False, stream=True, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        s.get('javascript:submitForm("pdf")')
        with response as content:
            with open(os.path.join(main_dir, 'nfe.pdf'), 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(content.raw, f)
                return True
return False
```

## Exception thrown:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:submitForm("pdf")'
```

Comment: No, requests only makes a HTTP request, it doesn't know anything about how to interpret a webpage. Try using Selenium instead.

Comment: @SuperStormer, actually I was trying to replace Selenium.

Comment: A better solution would be to look at the js function and see what its doing you can do the same using python, it might be sending a post request to some url, just inspect the webpage using a brwoser and look at what request the page is sending and construct a similar request  using requests.